# Accessing Subdirectories in WordPress Install

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, 404-error

I have scripts that are in a subdirectory of my WordPress install folder. They are on the same level as the /wp-content/ and /wp-admin/ folders. I'm running them as form processing but I've got the site set to permalinks with a post structure (http://www.example.com/testcategory/testpost).

My assumption is that I can't access the script files (I get a 404 error; an example would be like http://www.example.com/quform/test.php) because the .htaccess rewrite is getting in the way of it and it thinks it's a page on the site but there's no content for it.

I've tried to put an empty .htaccess file in the quform folder and then I tried to edit the code to turn the ReWrite Engine off but neither of those worked. I've searched around but none of the questions on here, though similar, have provided an answer for what I'm looking for.

Is there a way to create an exception for certain subdirectories in the .htaccess file?

### EDIT

Here is my .htaccess info

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
  suPHP_ConfigPath /home/millerme/etc/
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

### EDIT

So I was able to fix it but I still don't know what was causing it. Basically if I deleted a folder of file that was already on the server and then recreated it exactly as it was, it then was recognized by the server and I was able to access it.

The original files had file permissions of 775 so it wasn't a matter of file permissions being set incorrectly.

This site was migrated from another server where I downloaded the files and moved them over, so I'm assuming something happening that process. Any ideas on what would have caused the issue?

Comment: The rewrite rules in your `.htaccess` shouldn't affect anything, as it only triggers WordPress when a physical file (or directory) for the request does not exist. What's the contents of your `.htaccess`?

Comment: Ah interesting, I've added my .htaccess code above (I've modified the directory info in line 3 for safety on my end but it's all the same otherwise).

Comment: Well there's nothing there that should cause issue - as I mentioned previously, those rewrites only kick in when a file doesn't exist. Are you positive that the files you're trying to access exist, and that they Apache can read them?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic, I've just updated the question more. I figured out how to fix it but still don't know what was causing it...

Comment: Probably the files belonged to a user Apache could not read.